# Read and write system calls returning gibberish (C)

Tags: c, client, system, server

Im writing 2 integers between a server and a client and it gets jumbled in between. The client writes:

```
char playerMove[3];
char oppMove[3];
write(sock, playerMove, 3);
printf("Waiting on Opponent's move.\n");
read(sock, oppMove, 3);
printf("this was Opponent's move: %s\n", oppMove);
```

while the relevant server code is

```
char playerMove[3];
read(socket1, playerMove, 3);
printf("First move is: %s", playerMove);

write(socket2, playerMove, 3);
```

the terminal shows that the client says

```
Waiting on Opponent's move.
this was Opponent's move: �D�K
```

but in the server's terminal I can clearly see that it went through properly

```
First move is: 3 1
```

Can someone help me out here? Im new to C. Do I need to do something special to write "3 1" to my client?

Comment: You need to check the return values from `write` and `read` to make sure that they actually worked, and that the `read` actually got 3 bytes.

Comment: I have set everything as conditions like if(write(socket2, playerMove, 4) < 0){ perror("write failed");
 } and nothing showed up in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Your 3-element `char` array is too small to handle the *string* input of format "3 1". You need one more element to store the terminating null.

Also, in the client side, as per the code here, `playerMove` is used uninitalized. To avoid such cases, it's always adviced and a good practice to initalize the automatic local variables.

Comment: I tried changing it to 4 and I get 
this was Opponent's move: 
which is blank. Do I need to change the number of bytes for read and write too?

Comment: @REALLYANGRYSTUDENT yes. and where exactly you're setting the value `3 1`?

Comment: I tried doing it and its still blank

3 1 is retrieved from the stdin using fgets. code is
printf("Enter your move: \n");
            fgets(playerMove, 4, stdin);

Comment: @REALLYANGRYSTUDENT hmm.. do you know `fgets()` consider the trailing `\n`, too? You need to handle that yourself.

Comment: I did, thats not the problem, I have a check before that code that confirms that the strlen of playermove is only 3

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. Here buffer **oppMove** is set to 0 before using it.

```
char playerMove[3];
char oppMove[3];
memset(oppMove,'\0',3);
write(sock, playerMove, 3);
printf("Waiting on Opponent's move.\n");
read(sock, oppMove, 3);
printf("this was Opponent's move: %s\n", oppMove);
```

I also suggest to use buffer of 4 byte long as pointed out by Sourav Ghosh

Answer (score 0):

```
Read and write do not automatically append a NUL termination byte.
so do not expect them.

However there are a few problems with the code.

1) player move is not initialized, so trash is sent to the server.
2) the returned values from write and read should be checked 
   to assure the operations are successjul
3) the client call to printf is using '%s' which is expecting a 
   NUL terminated string,  however the value read is just some
   3 random characters (because the sent value was just some random characters.
suggestions:
1) initialize the player move array to some known value
2) in the printf() format string use '%c%c%c'  Not '%s'

regarding the server code.
it is totally random the something printable was displayed on the terminal
especially since the value read (and the buffer read into) 
is not NUL terminated.
the call to printf has the same problem with the format string
and needs the same fix as the client call to printf
```